# Is visitors/day counter broken?

Tags: bug

For the last couple days the "visitors/day" counter displayed in Site Stats (right sidebar) shows `0`:

[image]

I think it's incorrect, we have a few questions/answers/comments/votes every day, it's simply impossible to be `0`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug: see [Traffic (views, visits) isn't correctly registered on Site Analytics or Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51)

From [this page](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) it seems that the bug affects all Stack Exchange sites, except Stack Overflow.